# Moving files to the PersistantDataPath

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity and have some large video files in the project. The project is for both iOS and Android. Android being the main focus. I would like to be able to move them to the PersistentDataPath when the app is first installed. Right now they are only referenced from within a script, I'm using AVPro to play them, so they don't get included in the build unless I put them in the Resources folder or StreamingAssets and files cannot be deleted from those folders. Is there some way I can include the files in the APK in a way that they can be deleted after they are copied to the PersistantDataPath?

I have this script for copying files to the PersistantDataPath from the StreamingAssets folder, but I can't delete from there.

```
bool copyLargeVideoToPersistentDataPath(string videoNameWithExtensionName)
```

{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, videoNameWithExtensionName);

```
string persistentPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Videos");
persistentPath = Path.Combine(persistentPath, videoNameWithExtensionName);

bool success = true;

try
{
    using (FileStream fromFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (FileStream toFile = new FileStream(persistentPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fromFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                toFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            Debug.Log("Done! Saved to Dir: " + persistentPath);
            Debug.Log(videoNameWithExtensionName + " Successfully Copied Video to " + persistentPath);
            text.text = videoNameWithExtensionName + " Successfully Copied Video to " + persistentPath;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(videoNameWithExtensionName + " Failed To Copy Video. Reason: " + e.Message);
    text.text = videoNameWithExtensionName + " Failed To Copy Video. Reason: " + e.Message;
    success = false;
}

return success;
```

}

Comment: Few things:1.You don't have to put "Unity" in the title of your questions. That's why we have tags. 2.If you add a code or expect help in some certain language, you have to add the tag of that language. In this case, this is C#.

Comment: To answer your question, you can't delete data from the StreamingAssets folder. It's read only. You can delete data from `Application.persistentDataPath`. I have answered this in your first question. I also gave you a better solution(#4) which requires no copying. I said if you don't want copying, just create a local http server and stream the video on that device directly from the StreamingAssets folder.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand what it meant to create a local http server and stream from it. Is there any documentation or information you could link me to about that?

Comment: When you reply days later you are unnecessary extending this. I mentioned `HttpListener` in my other answer. All you have to do is Google that and take a look at the examples.  See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1245582/create-a-simple-http-server-on-the-streaming-asset.html) for an example in Unity. It's unnecessary long. If you have issues, you can create a new question.